# How to relay EWS email attachments to a REST endpoint using Viewpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exchangewebservices, rest-client, viewpoint

I need to forward an Outlook EWS email and its attachments to a Rails server.

The attachments I am getting with the Viewpoint gem are returned as `Viewpoint::EWS::Types::FileAttachment` objects.

How can I pass these attachments to a Rails server using the `rest-client` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to upload the files by using a `StringIO` and giving it a `:path`

```
# email is a Viewpoint::EWS::Types::Message
# email_endpoint is a RestClient::Resource

attachments = email.attachments.map do |attachment|
  file = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(attachment.content))
  file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type, :path }
  file.original_filename = attachment.file_name
  file.content_type = attachment.content_type
  file
end

response = email_endpoint.post(
  email: {
    subject: email.subject,
    attachments: attachments
  }
)
```

The `rest-client` library will automatically handle objects that respond to `:path` and `:read` as Files and use a multi-part upload.

Each attachment then shows up in Rails as an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` with the correct filename.